# made of VS made from (not duplicate, tricky one)

Tags: prepositions

Here I would like to ask a question about the usage of made of and made from.

I know the issue has been discussed on this forum many times before, but this time I would like to ask a tricky question that is not similar to the previous ones that have been discussed so far.

As we know, made of means that the materials do not change during the process of making, while made from means that they change into something different. 
For example,

1. Chairs are made of wood. (If you break the chairs, the scraps are still wood.)
2. Paper is made from wood. (There is no wood in the paper)

However, here comes my question. There are occasions when the materials are not combined, sewed, or stuck together. The manufacturers turn them into different things by simply changing their shapes.

Although you can still break them into pieces and find that they are still the same material, but you should not use "made of" but "made from" because they are neither units that are combined together (like bricks) nor the basic material that is normally used (like steel or wood).

For example,

1. The blanket is made of animal skin. (There are different pieces of animal skin sewed together. If you tear down any one of them, it's a piece of animal skin.)
2. The blanket is made from animal skin. (The blanket is made from a whole piece of animal skin. You can't see other pieces; therefore, it was "made from" animal skin.
3. The doll is made of the wood we found on the beach. (The doll consists of different pieces of wood.)
4. The doll is made from the wood we found on the beach. (The doll was originally a whole piece of wood.)
5. The drumhead is made from animal skin. (It's a whole piece of animal hide. You can't break it into smaller units. The piece of animal skin cannot be seen anymore if you tear the drumhead into fragments.)
6. The drumhead is made of animal skin. (It's composed of many pieces of animal skin. The pieces of skin are still obvious.)

Have I distinguished between them correctly?

Comment: Your definition was correct at the beginning. 'Made of' is a matter of composition. 'Made from' is a matter of manufacturing process changing the composition. I don't think that your following examples deviate from that definition.

Comment: @NigelJ I was not trying to say that the original definition was wrong. What I was saying is that, in some sentences, made of and made from can both be used in a justified way but with different meanings.

Comment: I think most native speakers would use _out of_ or the participle _using_ instead of _from_ in your example sentences.

Comment: Sorry everyone but I have a couple of problems with the comments Firstly both I and C.E.D. think that "from" can be used in the case of one material like wood "The desk is made from pine".or a composition like "Meringues are made from sugar and egg whites". The difference is "From" references the material whilst of references the manufacture. from preposition (MATERIAL).....of preposition (MADE OF)

Comment: @Brad "Made of" can be used if the process of manufacture is not complicated or focused on. For example, "The house is made of bricks.", means that these bricks are simply piled up and stuck together to become a house. On the other hand, "The doll is made from a brick" means that the doll was originally a brick, which was carved into a sculpture.